VueUse useIntersectionObserver causes initial flash before transition
I'm using useIntersectionObserver from VueUse to apply a fade-in transition on elements when they come into view. However, on initial page load, the elements briefly appear before the intersection observer triggers, causing a flash and applying the fade-in effect with a delay.
I want the elements to fade in smoothly as soon as the page loads, without this initial flash.
Here’s the reproduction:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-vd6hka?file=app%2Fpages%2Findex.vue
Observer component:
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="observerRef">
      <div :class="{ 'fade-in': isVisible }">
        <img crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://unsplash.it/600/400" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useIntersectionObserver } from '@vueuse/core';

const observerRef = ref(null);
const isVisible = ref(false);

const { stop } = useIntersectionObserver(
  observerRef,
  ([{ isIntersecting }]) => {
    isVisible.value = isIntersecting;
    if (isIntersecting) stop();
  }
);
</script>

Looking for a possible solution.

DOM APIs like this one are not guaranteed to be synchronous. You could add :style="{ visibility: isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }" if this serves the purpose

@EstusFlask is this the only solution? I need to maintain the transition as well. Is there way to use the class instead?

You can pack "visibility" property values inside classes. In your case the div should have "visibility: hidden" when it doesn't have fade-in class, one way or another

@EstusFlask I think it works, thank you. Could you make an answer please so I can mark it as a solution?

DOM APIs like IntersectionObserver are not guaranteed to be synchronous. It takes some time between an element being visible on the screen and an observer being triggered.
div that needs a transition should have visible: hidden style when it have fade-in, either through CSS class or dynamic styles:
<div
  :class="{ 'fade-in': isVisible }"
  :style="{ visibility: isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }"
>


Thanks! I also think adding opacity: 0 along with visibility: hidden makes sense to maintain the transition, since transitions on visibility don't work gradually.

You probably won't need visibility if you use opacity

I might keep it to disable interactions with the elements during transition. It's an additional layer of safety.
